# Access rights and their difference between public and protected members of a Java class?

Tags: java, class

I know this might be thought of as a duplicate question, but I think my question is a bit different from the previous questions.

The difference between public and protected members is that a public member acts as a protected member on in that it can be accessed from the **world** but a protected member cannot.

What does the term **world** mean? Does it mean from outside the class? If so how?

Is it by using the class name? Or they can be accessed by using the variable/method name directly without the current class being a subclass?

Comment: a protected member can be accessed from a subclass

Comment: The definition of 'world' is even given in the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html): _"The fourth column [world] indicates whether all classes have access to the member."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the word "world" means that it can be accessed from anywhere inside the project (no matter if they are in the same package). However the protected members means that they can only be accessed from other classes inside the **same** package. [Sources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)